# How to return an object rather than console log values

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JavaScript function to find the number of odd integers, number of negative integers, average, and median value.

The code is accomplishing everything that I wanted it to, however, I am wondering if I can rewrite it to get the function to return an object rather than just the console log values. I've also included a link to my JS Bin (https://jsbin.com/digagozuru/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
  var arrayAnalyzer = function(myArray) {

    var odds = 0;
    var negatives = 0;
    var avg;
    var median;

    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
      if (myArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
        odds += 1;
      }
      if (myArray[i] < 0) {
        negatives += 1;
      }
    }

    console.log("There are " + odds + " odd numbers.");
    console.log("There are " + negatives + " negative numbers.");

    var sum = myArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
      return previousValue + currentValue;
    });

    avg = sum / myArray.length;
    console.log("The average is " + avg.toFixed(2));

    var orderedArray = myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });

    if (orderedArray.length % 2 === 0) {
      var position1 = orderedArray.length / 2;
      var position2 = position1 - 1;
      median = (orderedArray[position1] + orderedArray[position2]) / 2;
    } else {
      var position = Math.floor(orderedArray.length / 2);
      median = orderedArray[position];
    }

    console.log("The median is " + median);
  };

  arrayAnalyzer([7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arrayAnalyzer = function(myArray) {

  var odds = 0;
  var negatives = 0;
  var avg;
  var median;

  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      odds += 1;
    }
    if (myArray[i] < 0) {
      negatives += 1;
    }
  }

  console.log("There are " + odds + " odd numbers.");
  console.log("There are " + negatives + " negative numbers.");

  var sum = myArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
  });

  avg = sum / myArray.length;
  console.log("The average is " + avg.toFixed(2));

  var orderedArray = myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  if (orderedArray.length % 2 === 0) {
    var position1 = orderedArray.length / 2;
    var position2 = position1 - 1;
    median = (orderedArray[position1] + orderedArray[position2]) / 2;
  } else {
    var position = Math.floor(orderedArray.length / 2);
    median = orderedArray[position];
  }

  console.log("The median is " + median);
  // Returns an object with named attributes
  return {
    odds:odds,
    negatives:negatives,
    avg:avg,
    median:median
  };
};

var myArray = arrayAnalyzer([7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3]);
console.log("Odds: " + myArray.odds +
  "\nNegatives: " + myArray.negatives +
  "\nAverage:" + myArray.avg +
  "\nMedian: " + myArray.median);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me. I am still new to JavaScript. Can you help me figure out where in my code I should put this? Thanks again.

Comment: The edit shows where to put it in the given code. The function gets all the calculations and puts them in a returned object.

Comment: Thank you! Your input was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get your question right, but why dont create an object at the beginning of your method and then write the values in the object as soon as you calculated them?

```js
var arrayAnalyzer = function(myArray) {

  var odds = 0;
  var negatives = 0;
  var avg;
  var median;
  var result = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      odds += 1;
    }
    if (myArray[i] < 0) {
      negatives += 1;
    }
  }

  result.negatives = negatives;
  result.odds = odds;

  var sum = myArray.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
  });

  avg = sum / myArray.length;
  result.avg = avg;

  var orderedArray = myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  if (orderedArray.length % 2 === 0) {
    var position1 = orderedArray.length / 2;
    var position2 = position1 - 1;
    median = (orderedArray[position1] + orderedArray[position2]) / 2;
  } else {
    var position = Math.floor(orderedArray.length / 2);
    median = orderedArray[position];
  }

  result.median = median;
  return result;
};
console.log(arrayAnalyzer([7, -3, 0, 12, 44, -5, 3]));
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I am now getting an unnecessary addition of     '[object Object]' in my output.

Comment: That is because you are using the console. The object returned is the exact same as the one in my code, but constructed differently.